# Storing the current line being analysed by flex

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, flex-lexer

In my parser generated by flex, I would like to be able to store each line in the file, so that when reporting errors, I can show the user the line that the error occurred on.

I could of course do this using a vector and read in all lines from the file before/after lexing, but this would just add to the time needed to parse a file.
What I thought I could instead do, is to store the line whenever a new-line character is matched, and insert the current line into a vector. So my questions is, is there a variable/macro that flex that stores the current line inside? (Something like `yyline` perhaps)

Note: I am also using bison

Comment: _"(Something like `yyline` perhaps)"_ Wasn't that `yylineno` IIRC?

Comment: yyline actually stores the line number, not the line itself.

Comment: Seems I misunderstood your question, sorry.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's ok, it seems other people did too :)

Comment: Wasn't there something like `yytext` that can be used to access the last parsed token text? You might accumulate this up to the next rule deduction, and provide this accumulated text along with the line number? If the rule is successfully deduced, you clear that accumulated context.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes that's a good idea actually, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By itself, lex/flex does not do what you ask.  As noted, you want this for reporting error messages.  (I do something like this in *[vi like emacs](http://invisible-island.net/vile/vile.html)*).

With lex/flex, the only way to *store* the entire line is to *record* each token from the current line into your own line-buffer.  That can be complicated, especially if your lexer has to handle multi-line content (such as comments or strings).

The `yytext` variable only shows you the most recently parsed token (and `yylength`, the corresponding length).  If your lexer does a simple `ECHO`, that is a token just like the ones you pay attention to.

Reading the file in advance as noted is one way to simplify the problem. In *vi like emacs*, the lexers read via a function from the in-memory buffer rather than from an input stream. It bypasses the normal stream-handling logic by redefining the `YY_INPUT` macro, e.g.,

```
#define YY_INPUT(buf,result,max_size) result = flt_input(buf,max_size)
```

Likewise, `ECHO` is redefined (since the editor reads the results back rather than letting them go to the standard output):

```
#define ECHO flt_echo(yytext, yyleng)
```

and it traps errors detected by the lexer with another redefinition:

```
#define YY_FATAL_ERROR(msg) flt_failed(msg);
```

However you do this, the `yylineno` value reported for a given token will be at the *end* of parsing a given token.

While it is nice to report the entire line in context in an error message, it is also useful to track the line and column number of each token -- various editors can deal with lines like this

```
filename:line:col:message
```

If you build up your line-buffer by tracking tokens, it might be relatively simple to track the column on which each token begins as well.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I have decided to read the lines in before calling the lexer/parser and then redefine the yyinput macro so that it gets the input from the pre-read buffer.

Comment: Actually `yyinput` itself is normally not a macro, but you can provide your own function if you define `YY_NO_INPUT`.